# WPF Shape With Transparent Fill But Solid Stroke Possible?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, expression-blend

I'm trying to create a shape in my WPF application that has a transparent fill but a solid stroke.  I only see one property called `Opacity` on the `Path` that I drew, which turns both the stroke and fill transparent.  Is it possible to only turn the fill transparent and not the stroke?

EDIT: I need the fill to be a transparent color and the stroke to be a solid color.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a `SolidColorBrush` with an opacity for the fill.

```
<Rectangle Stroke="Red" Margin="10"  StrokeThickness="5" Height="50" Width="100">
    <Rectangle.Fill>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="Red" Opacity=".5"/>
    </Rectangle.Fill>
</Rectangle>
```

If you don't need to bind the opacity or color you can also use shorthand: `Fill="#80FF0000"` where the first 2 characters are a hex code for the alpha value.

Result:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/wRBTnr5.png]

Comment: What he actually means is a Fill Brush with an Opacity less than 1.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I do need to display a color as the fill but it need to be semi-transparent.  The stroke I need to be a solid color with no transparency.

Comment: Ah, translucent not transparent :)

Comment: That's what I need!  Thanks a lot

Comment: @Clemens no where did he mention that he means Fill Brush with Opacity less than 1.

Answer (score 1):

There are many shapes in WPF as stated [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms747393(v=vs.100).aspx).

> WPF provides a number of ready-to-use Shape objects. All shape objects inherit from the Shape class. Available shape objects include Ellipse, Line, Path, Polygon, Polyline, and Rectangle.

So you want transparent fill but a solid stroke?  Why not just do this

```
 <Rectangle Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="5" Fill="Transparent"/>
```

Comment: Not Rectangle but  a Shape.

Comment: @AnjumSKhan A rectangle derives from shape in WPF, so using a rectangle as an example applies to any shape.. Shape is an abstract class so of course it can't be used in XAML...

Comment: @Cyral And why my answer is wrong ?

Comment: @AnjumSKhan Look at the comments on mine.

Answer (score -1):

Use `Polygon` class.

```
<Polygon Fill="Transparent" Points="1,2,35,50,90,20" Stroke="Aqua" StrokeThickness="2" />
```

Comment: @Jeff see my answer plz

Comment: Why my answer is wrong ?

Comment: The question is about SHAPE and not Rectangle.